# video quality is not good

Tags: 16.04, graphics, radeon, amd-graphics

I have switched from Windows to Ubuntu 16.04. But I'm not sure my graphics card driver was installed correctly. I'm experiencing poor video quality in VLC. My graphics card is AMD Radeon HD 6570.

Here is the output of the command: lspci -nnk | grep -A2 VGA

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Turks PRO [Radeon HD 6570/7570/8550] [1002:6759]
    Subsystem: PC Partner Limited / Sapphire Technology Turks PRO [Radeon HD 6570/7570/8550] [174b:e193]
    Kernel driver in use: radeon
```

Comment: Have you installed the drivers separately?

Comment: To enable the proprietary drivers, you should try to go in your System Properties > Drivers and enable the driver. If you can't see it, try to install Catalyst/fglrx. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver

Comment: @tobiasBoraL: fglrx is incompatible with the kernel released with Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of the terminal command `lspci -nnk | grep -A2 VGA`? Thanks.

Comment: I have tried to install fglrx . But I saw that for 16.04 amd released no fglrx!!!

Comment: The Radeon driver is already pre-installed in Ubuntu 16.04, and your video card seems to be fully supported with the  xserver-xorg-video-ati package. You should have a look at the Ubuntu ATI documentation [here.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver)

Comment: How would I know if my graphics driver is working properly?As in windows I could see my display resolution.

Answer (score 0):

The Open Source Radeon driver for some ATI/AMD graphics cards and APUs, "xserver-xorg-video-ati package" is already pre-installed in Ubuntu 16.04, and your video card's *TURKS* chipset seems to be fully supported with those drivers. You could also opt for (not recomeded) the closed-source, proprietary *fglrx* driver called *AMD Catalyst,* from AMD Inc. The Open Source Radeon driver supports some older chipsets that fglrx does not.

To configure screen resolution under Ubuntu 16.04:

```
>System Settings >Screen Display
```

Select the appropriate screen resolution there.